# Common static mount for EKS pods

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks, persistent-volumes, kubernetes-pvc

Lets say I have a folder /mydata and it contains some .tar.gz files (plugins). Once I populate this folder (via some script), its contents won't change (read only). Now my requirement is I want this folder to be mounted on multiple pods running on EKS cluster. Meaning each pod which has this folder mounted, will all see the same content and should be able to read the binary data (no writes).

What is the best way to achieve this? I am confused by going through some searching. Some suggest EBS volume, some suggest EFS. Can someone please help as to what would be the right way to mount such a folder in multiple pods and possibly with some examples. Thanks

Comment: I'd `COPY` them into your Docker image, assuming the size of the tar files is reasonable (for a typical "plugin" it will be).

Comment: Thanks @DavidMaze. In my case, both the app which runs in the pod as well as the plugins are 3rd party. I don't have control over the image building process